# JavaScript - Angular Velocity by Vector - 2D

Tags: javascript, math, vector, physics

I am making a game in JavaScript, with the Canvas API.

I perform circle to segment collision, and I need to calculate the anglar velocity for the circle by its velocity vector, I use this formula to do it:

```
ball.av = ball.v.length() / ball.r

// ball.av = angular velocity
// ball.v = velocity vector, contains x and y values
// .length() = returns initial velocity (pythagoras) for example: return Math.sqrt(ball.v.x * ball.v.x + ball.v.y * ball.v.y)
// ball.r = radius
```

Now since a square root can't be negative, this won't work when the ball is supposed to rotate anti-clockwise. So, I need a signed version of the initial velocity that also can be negative, how do I calculate that?

I've heard about that the Wedge product is working for this, and I've read many articles about it, but I still don't understand how to implement it to my code, please help!

Comment: Just to understand: The circle represents a solid object which may rotate around its center while the whole object moves forward. And you want to simulate the interaction of this inner rotation with the velocity change during the collision with a wall/the ground?

Comment: Yes, I already know the velocities, so that's not a problem, the collision is totally perfect, it's just about setting the angular velocity so it can spin, using the responding velocities in the collision.

Comment: What is it that spins and how, under which physical principle or idea, does the spin change?

Comment: To make to easier to understand: A ball that SHOULD spin by it's x and y velocities

Comment: The balls angular velocity is added to the balls angle in each frame, so the ball spins when it moves.

Comment: So why should that change? Just keep adding the same increment to the angle of the ball. Or if this goes for effect, reverse the sign of the angle increment.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yzb9P/1/

Comment: Ok, so you *want* an interaction of velocity and rotation as an effect of the collision. The only remaining question is, how realistic should it be. The inner rotation binds energy, this goes away from the kinetic energy, influencing the velocity after rotation,...

Comment: as realistic as possible, all I've done by now is realistic right?

Comment: There's co-efficient friction and elasticy

Comment: Goto line 233 at fiddle in JS for the main problem

Comment: I'm not claiming to have a ready solution, I'm just interested in getting more information towards your question. http://jesseenterprises.net/amsci/1984/09/1984-09-fs.html has a nice qualitative description of occurring effects, but no formulas.

Comment: But I need a formula, not a text, come on! thanks anyway

Comment: I believe there is no simple formula. Maybe that I'm overthinking the problem and there is a useful approximation for "hard balls" where the interaction time at the collision is very small. You should ask about that in the physics.stackexchange.com forum. I found several loosely connected questions, but no helpful answers so far.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yzb9P/2/ Why not counter-clockwise -.-

Comment: There are more problems with the dynamics, if you put the ball on the slope, it should still accelerate, but instead is very slowly gliding down, nearly coming to a stop on the slope (that last might be a visual misconception).

Comment: 4 people want to close this question? or is it 1 with 4 accounts maybe?

Comment: It is the elasticy and the co efficient friction that stops it from gliding in max speed down the hill, so that is not a problem

Comment: It should roll down if there is friction, and glide down if there is no friction. Both with acceleration, but the size of acceleration will differ.

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, if the ball is rolling on a surface then the angular velocity would be the cross product of the velocity with the surface normal over the radius.

```
ball.av = CrossProduct(surfaceNormal, ball.v) / radius;
```

But if you are always on a flat surface along the x direction then this simplifies to this:

```
ball.av = -ball.v.x / ball.r;
```

Here is crossproduct for you if you don't have it.

```
float CrossProduct(const Vector2D & v1, const Vector2D & v2) const
{
    return (v1.X*v2.Y) - (v1.Y*v2.X);
}
```

NOTE: if the ball rolls backwards just add a '-' sign to your calculations or swap the parameters in the crossProduct call but I think they are right as I've written them.

Surface normal is a perpendicular normalized (unit) vector from a surface. In your case surface normal is the normalized vector from the contact point to the centre of the circle.

As a side note to remove the component of gravity into a surface as a ball is rolling do this:

```
vec gravity;

gravity = gravity - surfaceNormal*dot(surfaceNormal, gravity);
```

you can then apply the resultant gravity as a ball is rolling down a surface.

Comment: Ok but what is "surfaceNormal"?

Comment: and how do I calculate it?

Comment: Surface normal is a perpendicular vector from a surface. In your case surface normal is a normalized (unit) vector from the contact point to the centre of the circle.

Comment: As for your demo. I looked at the code and it seems OK without entirely following it but the demo itself works fine so I assume it is good. The one issue you have with the demo is that you are not applying gravity when the ball is in contact with a surface. You need to but if just adding a gravity velocity is causing it to bounce you can simply apply gravity with the component into the surface removed. I'll add the code to my original answer.